# UIScrollView on top of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am making an app which has a scroll view between three view controllers. I am making a help menu that should appear on top of the scroll view, as another scroll view, containing 3 images that explain the app. So that's a scroll view on top of a scroll view. Here is my code so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

StopwatchViewController *svc = [[StopwatchViewController alloc]init];
[self addChildViewController:svc];
[self.scrollView addSubview:svc.view];
[svc didMoveToParentViewController:self];

BarsViewController *bvc = [[BarsViewController alloc] init];
CGRect frame = bvc.view.frame;
frame.origin.x = 320;
bvc.view.frame = frame;

[self addChildViewController:bvc];
[self.scrollView addSubview:bvc.view];
[bvc didMoveToParentViewController:self];

TimerViewController *tvc = [[TimerViewController alloc]init];
frame = tvc.view.frame;
frame.origin.x = 320 * 2;
frame.origin.y = 44;
tvc.view.frame = frame;

[self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tvc.pan];
[self addChildViewController:tvc];
[self.scrollView addSubview:tvc.view];
[tvc didMoveToParentViewController:self];

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*3, self.view.frame.size.height);
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(320,0);

[self.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

// THIS IS WHERE IT GOES WRONG

if ([[ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 568 ) {
    NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Guide Page One.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Guide Page One.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Guide Page One.png"], nil];
    self.helpScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(280 * 3, 528);
    self.helpScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

CGFloat xPos = 0.0;

for (UIImage *image in images) {
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 0.0, 280, 528);
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    xPos += 280;
    // assuming ARC, otherwise release imageView
}

self.helpScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(340,20);
}
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(showHelp)
                                             name:@"showWelcomeMessage"
                                           object:nil];
}
```

The first part of my code (up to the comment) works fine. I can swipe between my three view controllers. What I want to happen next, is for the user to press a button, and for this new scroll view to appear on top (leaving a 20px margin from the edges). It should have a navigation bar at the top, like so:

[image]

..to allow the user to quit the help menu, and return to the app. I am really lost here, because I am only a beginner to Objective-C.

I just want to have a scroll view on top of the main scroll view which will present 3 images to explain the app.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I really don't know what to do next and i can't seem to find anything on this site similar to my problem. Please ask for more info if needed!

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

if user press next button you want to scroll the content like page ?

Comment: Yeah, they can press next to go to the next picture, or just scroll

Comment: If you have any idea of how to accomplish all of this, then I would be really grateful is you could write some example code of how to implement this into my app. Please ask for more info if needed.

Comment: Then do the following 

 
1) create a int variable

int page=1;

2) In next button action add the following

-(void)nextButtonAction: (id)sender{

if(page<=3){

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

 self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*page, self.view.frame.size.height);
    
    }];
page++;
}
}

Comment: Thank you, but it's not just the next button that I need. It's the whole pop up. I have tried to explain it better here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480552/first-time-app-launch-tour-guide